# progress-bar updated with setInterval zero still takes time to finish

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, setinterval

Sorry for being very noob, but I started to learn JavaScript and have a little problem.

In the following code sample, the progress bar goes from 0 to 100 in 1 second, however, the "time" variable is set to 0 milliseconds, used by setInterval. I would expect the progressbar to be instantly at 100% when I press the button. (I will have progresses that will take less than a second to finish and I want to show them properly.) Looks like the setInterval is not using the given time as milliseconds.

So my question is, how can I set up the setInterval to use milliseconds, as it should be? (I know it will behave strange if you click the button a second time, but now this does not matter.)

Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="theButton">click</button>
<progress id="progressbar" min="0" value="0" max="100"></progress>
<span class="progress-value">0%</span>
    <script>
        $('#theButton').click(function(){
            var progressbar = $('#progressbar'),
                max = progressbar.attr('max'),
                time = 0,   
                value = progressbar.val();

            var loading = function() {
                value += 1;
                addValue = progressbar.val(value);

                $('.progress-value').html(value + '%');

                if (value == max) {
                    clearInterval(animate);
                }
            };

            var animate = setInterval(function() {
                loading();
            }, time);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle or plunker for this?

Comment: Created a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/XBdAJSbEqV4lBukrgZNQ?p=info